# macOS: How to zoom in on WKWebView Video

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, wkwebview

This is a macOS web browser app. My goal is to be able to press a button while watching an online video and fill the entire view with the video.

Here's an app that does what i want to achieve:

[image]

Any idea of how this is done? Any help that would point me in the right direction would be appreciated!

ContentView

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack{
                Button("Zoom Video") {
                    // Zoom function
                }
            }
            
            WebView()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

WebView

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import AppKit

struct WebView: NSViewRepresentable {
    
 
        typealias NSViewType = WKWebView
        
        let webView: WKWebView
        
        init() {
            webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FT3ODSg1GFE")!))
        }
        
        func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {

            webView.configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "fullScreenEnabled") // fullscreen
            webView.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]
          return  webView
        }
        func updateNSView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        }
     
}
```

Comment: Well, you could execute javascript to emulate a click on the fullscreen button  with `WKWebView.evaluateJavaScript`, but that doesn't work quite well because full-screening the page requires an explicit user action which `.click()` doesn't qualify as.

Comment: I think the video you provided is not web view, but read html and show it in native SwiftUI. In that case, the button can easily implemented by if else